# Upgrading Rails 5.1 to 5.2, can't find gem versions, but seems like all the requirements are met

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

Here's a fragment from the log.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:
    active_model_serializers was resolved to 0.10.10, which depends on
      actionpack (>= 4.1, < 6.1)
    rails (= 5.2.4.1) was resolved to 5.2.4.1, which depends on
      actionpack (= 5.2.4.1)
   rails-controller-testing (= 0.1.1) was resolved to 0.1.1, which depends on
      actionpack (~> 5.x)
```

I just don't get what exactly it is missing. From what I understand, actionpack 5.2.4.1 fits all of the requirements from other gems, but something is not happy. There are bunch of other gems that appear to have similar issues, where at least at the first glace there shouldn't be any conflicts.

Any suggestions on how to fix that?

Comment: Try removing your `Gemfile.lock` and see if it can sort it out. Second step is to remove constraints from the `Gemfile` itself to see if it can find a match.

Comment: Tried removing gemfile.lock - still the same. Removing constraints from active_model_serializers and rails-controller-testing doesn't help and I kind of want to specify rails version.

Comment: Rails you have to specify, but a lot of the other things can be left open to interpretation. You may want to experiment by making a separate test directory with a `Gemfile` in it and strip it down to just a couple of these things to see what versions they actually want.

Comment: Would you put your Gemfile in your question along with any failure output from calling `gem install actionpack --version '5.2.4.1'` on the command line? Additionally  are you using rbenv or rvm to manage your ruby versions and gems installed with those versions?

Comment: Look through all of the reported version conflicts. Most of them will resolve correctly, but one of them isn't. Can you post the whole conflict log?

Comment: Thank you Chris, I didn't expect to have so many false positives. Once I looked through the whole list, I've found 2 conflicts that resolved it. Thanks again!

Comment: @EugeneO. You should add a reasonably explaining answer to this question because people looking to answer it will find that this no longer is a question after spending their 2 - 3 minutes at the least.

Comment: @ARK question should probally be closed through "It's caused by a typo or problem that can no longer be reproduced." as its unlikely to help anybody else.

Comment: @max right on. Closing is better option.